# Ignore first character of string - JS - Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, match, regex-negation

I'm trying to write a Regex that will ignore the first character of a string and start with the second character.

e.g.

```
str = "14";
test = "4";
```

This will match ONLY if 4 is is position 2 (end of the string) and NOT at the start, the following will fail

```
str = "21";
test = "4";
```

I'm rubbish at Regex and all the options I've tried so far haven't worked.

My current code is like so

```
filters = filters.replace(/,\s*$/, '');
objRegex = new RegExp('\\/^.{1}(.*)/' + filters, 'gi');
```

Where filters is a random string consisting of two characters. The current Regex was copied from another SO post but it doesn't work and given my limited knowledge I'm not sure how to make it work, anyone able to help?

Thanks!

Comment: is all you want to do is check if the second character is a specific number?

Comment: pretty much but the number isn't static, it'll change so I can't rely on checking against a specific number, it needs to check against position and if that number is at the end of the string then match

Comment: Any reason that you can't use `substr`? Ex: `if( str.substr(-1) === '4' ); // If the last character in str equals '4'`

Comment: I've got it working using a substring, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a Regex is a bit overkill, how about something like this:

```
var stringToSearch = '14';
var stringToFind = '4';
if (stringToSearch && stringToSearch.length === 2 &&
    stringToSearch[1] === stringToFind) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use substring method ?

```
str = "14";
test = "4";
var str = str.substring(0, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following pattern: 
"^[\w]{1}4$"